# Is this series diverging? If not, what's the sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series

The series in question:

$$\frac{5}{7^2+11^2} + \frac{9}{11^2+15^2} + \frac{13}{15^2+19^2} + \dots$$

Or in a concise form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {\frac{4i+1}{(4i+3)^2+(4i+7)^2}}$$

I tried to solve, and find a closed form of the above summation but got no luck. The denominator could not be factorised and decomposed and I couldn't transform the series into a telescopic one to solve it either.

I asked this to my maths professor and he looked at the series in question for a while, and declared it as a diverging one, so it can't be solved. He looked unsure.

Was he right? Is it a divergent series? If not, how can I solve it, if I can? Thanks!

Comment: standard comment: what have you tried?

Comment: **Hint:** Think of the $i$th term for some really big $i$. Try to approximate it with something simpler.

Comment: WolframAlpha is a great place for checking things like this: it concludes that your professor is correct, and this is a [divergent series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%3D1+to+infty+(4i%2B1)%2F((4i%2B3)%5E2%2B(4i%2B7)%5E2))

Comment: He looked at the series for a while and still was unsure? Maybe it's time to switch to a different professor.

Comment: @Fakemistake though the answer has now been given :P, I took the series to be convergent by default and tried to factorise the denominator, trying to split the fraction and see whether the resultant terms progressively cancel out each other.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen sorry, didn't quite get what you meant... Could you elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: Okay. This: Assume that $i$ is humongous. Then $1$ is tiny compared to $4i$, so drop it from the numerator. Do the same in the denominator: $3$ and $7$ are tiny compared to $4i$, so drop those too. Now the $i$th term looks more like $4i/\bigl((4i)^2+(4i)^2=1/(8i)$. Therefore, it is a good bet to assume that the $i$th term is approximately $1/(8i)$. The factor $1/8$ is of no consequence for convergence, so our series should have the convergence properties of $\sum 1/i$, which is divergent. Now make this rigorous, for example by doing a limit comparison test with $\sum 1/i$.

Comment: … This method needs to be used with care, though. This one was simple, but there are many pitfalls, which is why you *have* to go back and do it rigorously. The method merely tells you what you ought to try. In particular, look out for cancellation effects, when two similar, large terms are *subtracted* rather than *added*. If the denominator had looked like $(4i+7)^2-(4i+3)^2$, for example, you should first expand the polynomials, find the $i^2$ terms drop out, and *then* apply the method.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Heuristically, the summand is the ratio of a linear polynomial to a quadratic polynomial, and so it grows similarly to the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1 i$, which diverges. This tells us that the original sum diverges as well. To show this, note that for sufficiently large $i$ ($i>80$, to be exact) we have
$$\frac{4i+1}{(4i+3)^2+(4i+7)^2} = \frac{4i+1}{32i^2+80i+58} \geq \frac{4i}{33i^2} = \frac{4}{33}\frac 1 i$$
Now you can use the comparison test.

Comment: I think (and it's been a looong time) that  L'Hopital's Rule applies - you basically used it for a specific value of $\textit{i}$ .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Would you apply L'hospital's rule and take the derivative of the function with respect to i? That will show that the terms converge but series still diverges

Comment: @Hugh but it would be the harmonic series which is well-known to diverge.  Remember: terms -->0 is required but is not sufficient for series convergence.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Maybe you mean the en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem ? But using Stolz-Cesàro for this problem would be unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's what I mean. L'Hospital wont show that the sum converges, only if the terms converge. The fact that the quotient of derivatives is a harmonic series shouldn't indicate divergence. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Hugh  I guess I took it as a given that the result of L'Hopital would be obvious that it was the harmonic series :-(

Comment: So my professor was right! Whew! But though you've shown that this particular linear-numerator-quadratic-denominator is divergent, is it true for all such series which have a linear numerator expression, and a quadratic denominator? Do all such essentially simplify into the harmonic series? Thanks!

Comment: @MihirChaturvedi As a matter of fact, if the summand is a rational function of the form $f(x)/g(x)$ where $f$ has degree $n$ and $g$ has degree $m$, then the series converges iff the series with summand $1/x^{n-m}$ converges.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm going wrong here somewhere, but if $f(x)$ has a degree $n$ and $g(x)$ has a degree $m$, then for a convergent series, isn't it necessary that $m$ be greater than $n$? Surely only if the denominator is larger than the numerator in a rational function, can the series have a chance of being a convergent one. Therefore, the test, as you mentioned, should be $1/x^{m-n}$ and not $1/x^{n-m}$. Am I right?

Comment: My bad, I should have said $1/x^{m-n}$.